# Why does my iphone app does not zoom-in every time I launch the app in the application manager?

Tags: iphone

It's weird that my app does not zoom in when running in the application manager of the iphone like the other apps do. Do you think the problem is related to the simulator? Or have I done something wrong in the settings of the project?

Comment: 1. Define "zoom in"—are you just referring to the visual effect on launch?  2.  You mention the simulator—does this problem (whatever it is) occur on the simulator, the device, or both?

Comment: What I mean is, when I run the app in the application manager, it does not zoom-in which is the visual effect when I launch the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the background of your window is black, and you have no Default.png image in your bundle, then the zoom effect may be unnoticeable.  It's even worse if you don't have a status bar.

Comment: Hi Sir. Thanks. Could you please elaborate more about the Default.png image in the bundle?

Comment: THanks alot!! I figured it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Whatever image is in your Default.png will get displayed between the moment that your app is first tapped until your first viewController handles its viewDidLoad (or viewDidAppear) method.  It is a good way to make the user think that your app is very responsive, when in fact your app is still loading.